# Snakemake report with Rmarkdown and custom.css file

Tags: r-markdown, report, workflow, bioinformatics, snakemake

Below an example of [Snakemake Rmd report](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=rmd#external-scripts) with a [custom.css](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html#html-css).

```markdown
---
title: "Test Report"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
params:
   rmd: "report.Rmd"
output:
  html_document:
     css: "custom.css" 

---

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document.
Test include from snakemake `r snakemake@input`.
```

This specific example does not work because Snakemake moves the .rmd file to a temporary location.

> File custom.css not found in resource path
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99

The trivial solution would be moving the `custom.css` to where `report.rmd` is rendered, but we don't have this location. In addition, we can not use the `snakemake` directive on the header, as it is only available after it.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? The only solution I can think is patching Snakemake to accept specific header parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snakemake object is not available Rmd preamble ([see here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/8d82d6d58d107959c13aa96cf4f7b470c5a80062/snakemake/script.py#L723)).

The solution I found was to use a `css` chunk instead of the CSS parameter:

````
---
title: "Test Report"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
params:
   rmd: "report.Rmd"
output:
  html_document
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.Sidebar {
   background-image: url('logo.png');

```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document.
Test include from snakemake `r snakemake@input`.
````

Although this works fine for my use case, I think it would be helpful to have the `snakemake` object in the preamble.

Answer (score 2):

The source directory of the script file is reported as "scriptdir". Maybe you are able to use that?

```
---
title: "Test Report"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
params:
  rmd: "report.Rmd"
output:
  html_document:
    css: "`r snakemake@scriptdir`/custom.css" 

---

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document.
Test include from snakemake `r snakemake@input`.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution will not work:
```bash
sh: 1: snakemake@scriptdir: not found
pandoc: /custom.css: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
```
It seems the `snakemake` variable is not usable from the Rmd header.

Comment: I forgot the `r`after the backtick. Does it work now?

Comment: Hi @JohannesKöster, thanks for the help. It seems the currently implementation does not support the snakemake object on the markdown header, see [for example](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1177) and [code](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/8d82d6d58d107959c13aa96cf4f7b470c5a80062/snakemake/script.py#L723). I was starting to draft a PR, but I found an alternative that worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe your syntax is wrong. according to [Rmarkdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html)

```
output:
  html_document:
    css: "style.css"
```

update your yaml header and see if we get a different error for the css other than the "File custom.css not found in resource path" that you got previously now that we corrected the YAML format

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Although you are correct, your input does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a somewhat satisfying solution to this problem. Since, as previously mentioned, the snakemake object is not available in the YAML header of Rmarkdown documents, I define the CSS for the document afterwards.

I found my solution after reading the following pages from the R Markdown Cookbook: [Apply custom CSS](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html#html-css), [Read external scripts into a chunk](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/option-code.html#option-code) as well as [Use variables in chunk options](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-variable.html#chunk-variable).

````
---
title: "Test Report"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
params:
   rmd: "report.Rmd"
output:
   html_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
css_file <- paste0(snakemake@scriptdir, "/style.css")
```

```{css, code=xfun::read_utf8(css_file), echo=FALSE}
``` 

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document.
Test include from snakemake `r snakemake@input`.
````

Basically, in the first `r` code chunk I access the snakemake object and get the path to the CSS file. In the second `css` code chunk I read from this filepath the external CSS file.